# How to make Selenium open a default folder when asked to choose a file?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to make Selenium open a default folder when asked to choose a file?

I'm trying to upload a file in a website using Selenium but when I click to upload the file and the website opens the folders always open in my home directory.
I want to always open in a certain folder and choose the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

You can set your last directory in preference.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"selectfile.last_directory" : "/path/to/upload"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "/path/to/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Comment: That helped a lot but do you know a way that I can select the file to be uploaded?

Comment: Nevermind i found that u need to get the id of the input and send_keys with the path of the file

Answer (score 0):

Get the id of the input camp

HTML code on the webpage:
`<input class="file fl_arquivoFormFile" style="display: inline; width: 254px;">`

Like:
`upload = self.driver.find_element_by_id("fl_arquivoFormFile")`

And:
`send.keys(path_to_file) #/home/viper/Documents/file`